# Redirecting to different actions without using a query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to figure out the best way to do the following (there are a few ways I can think of, but I want to know what the best way to handle it is):

---

A user is putting together a shipment, and then clicks the "Send" link, which sends him to the `/shipments/:id/confirm` page. The `confirm` action checks to see if the user has a completed `ShippingAddress`; if not, it sends him to the `ShippingAddress#new`. (If he does, it render the `confirm` page.

I want the user to be able to complete the `ShippingAddress#new` page, submit it, and then be redirect back to the `/shipments/:id/confirm`. How can I do that? How can I pass the `:id` to the `ShippingAddress#new` page without doing something like `redirect_to new_shipping_address_path(shipment_id: @shipment.id)` in the `Shipment#confirm` action? Or is that the best way to do that?

---

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  def confirm
    @shipment = Shipment.where(id: params[:id]).first

    unless current_user.has_a_shipping_address?
        # Trying to avoid having a query string, but right now would do the below:
        #   in reality, there's a bit more logic in my controller, handling the cases
        #   where i should redirect to the CardProfiles instead, or where I don't pass the
        #   shipment_id, and instead use the default shipment.
        redirect_to new_shipping_address_path(shipment_id: @shipment.id)
    end
  end
end


class ShippingAddressesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @shipment = Shipment.where(id: params[:shipment_id]).first
  end

  def create
    @shipment = Shipment.where(id: params[:shipment_id]).first

    redirect_to confirm_shipment_path(@shipment)
  end
end
```

---

[In reality, there is also a `CardProfiles#new` page that needs to be filled out after the shipping address is].

Comment: Why don't you render the `shipping_address/new` in shipment#confirm if the address is nil?

Comment: I explain in comments on the @agmcleod's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling render instead of redirect_to, and set the id into an instance variable. Adjust the view logic to pull that instance variable if it exists.

```
@shipment_id = @shipment.id
render new_shipping_address_path
```

In the view

```
<%= form_for @shipment_address do |f| %>
  <% if @shipment_id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :shipment_id, @shipment_id %>
  <% end %>
```

I don't know your view logic entirely, but giving an example.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I wish it would, but that won't work—I need instance variables that are defined in `ShippingAddressesController`. For example, `@shipping_address` (you have it called `@shipment_address`, above). But I also have a method that returns an instance variable named `copy` that contains copy for the view depending on the controller which is rendering the view.

Comment: Ah okay. One other option then is storing it in a session, but just make sure to clear it and such appropriately. Could also maybe do a path such as `new/:id` where you setup an alternative route to go to the new action as well. Then check against the id in the controller to load it in the view.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that, but that seems a little brittle. May be the best way, then… or just sticking it in the URL, e.g. `?shipment_id=abcdxyz`